# How to present image in html which is originally from the Mat data type of GoCV

Tags: javascript, html, opencv, go

I want to implement two things, now I can not fulfill one of them.
I make a WebSocket server using main.go, then I open index.html using live server of vscode. On the html page, when I click "拍照" button, I call the server to run GoCV to take a selfie using my webcam of notebook. Everything is achieve up to now. Finally I need to pass that selfie data to html page and present, I try to convert the img to []byte like "img.ToBytes()" then pass to websocket in golang code, I convert that blob to objectURL then pass to  tag in html , then the page just shows up an image icon without image. I don't know how to solve this problem. Maybe the data format is illegal, how to do it correctly?

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
    "gocv.io/x/gocv"
)

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  1024,
    WriteBufferSize: 1024,
}

func homePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Home Page")
}

func reader(conn *websocket.Conn) {
    Img := gocv.NewMat()
    for {

        // read in a message
        messageType, p, err := conn.ReadMessage()
        fmt.Println(string(p))
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
        if err := conn.WriteMessage(messageType, p); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }

        if string(p) == "someone is going to take a selfie" {
            webcam, err := gocv.OpenVideoCapture(0)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Error opening video capture device: %v\n", 0)
                return
            }
            fmt.Println("1")
            fmt.Println("2")
            img := gocv.NewMat()
            fmt.Println("3")

            if ok := webcam.Read(&img); !ok {
                fmt.Printf("Device closed: %v\n", 0)
                return
            }
            fmt.Println("4")

            Img = img
            fmt.Println("5")

            webcam.Close()

            fmt.Println("什麼都關了")

            //傳字
            conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(1000000000))

            w, err := conn.NextWriter(websocket.BinaryMessage)
            if err != nil {
                return
            }

            w.Write(img.ToBytes())

            if err := w.Close(); err != nil {
                return
            }
        }
        if string(p) == "someone is going to save the selfie" {
            fmt.Println("要存照片囉！！")
            gocv.IMWrite("selfie.jpg", Img)
        }
    }
}

func wsEndpoint(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    upgrader.CheckOrigin = func(r *http.Request) bool { return true }

    // upgrade this connection to a WebSocket
    ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    log.Println("客戶端連接")

    reader(ws)
}

func setupRoutes() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", homePage)
    http.HandleFunc("/ws", wsEndpoint)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("伺服器開啟")
    setupRoutes()
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>GoCV作業延伸</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>GoCV作業延伸</h2>
    <div>
      <button id="capture" onclick="captureHandler();">拍照</button>
      <button id="save" onclick="saveHandler();">儲存</button>
    </div>
    <div><img id="img" /></div>
    <div class="column">
      <label for="upload" class="button file-label">Select Image</label>
      <input id="upload" class="hidden" type="file" accept="image/*" />
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img id="upload-image" />
    </div>
    <script>
      let socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/ws");
      console.log("Attempting Connection...");

      socket.onopen = (capture) => {
        console.log("Successfully Connected");
        socket.send("Hi From the Client!");
      };

      socket.onclose = (event) => {
        console.log("Socket Closed Connection: ", event);
        socket.send("Client Closed!");
      };
      //?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
      const uploadButton = document.getElementById("upload");

      const imgDOM = document.getElementById("upload-image");
      function createImageFromFile(img, file) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          console.log(URL.createObjectURL(file));
          img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
          img.onload = () => {
            URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
            resolve(img);
          };
          img.onerror = () => reject("Failure to load image.");
        });
      }

      function getFileBase64Encode(blob) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const reader = new FileReader();

          reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
          reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
          reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
        });
      }

      function handleFiles() {
        console.log(this);
        const fileList = this.files;
        console.log(fileList);
        const [file] = fileList;
        console.log(file);
        const p1 = createImageFromFile(imgDOM, file);
        const p2 = getFileBase64Encode(file);
        console.log(p1);
        Promise.all([p1, p2]).then((result) => {
          const [img, b64] = result;
        });
      }

      uploadButton.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);
      //?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
      let capture = document.getElementById("capture");
      let imgdom = document.getElementById("img");
      socket.onmessage = (e) => {
        console.log(e);
        console.log(e.data);
        let blob = e.data;
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        function createImageFromBlob(img, blob) {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log(blob);
            console.log(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
            img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            img.onload = () => {
              URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
              resolve(img);
            };
            img.onerror = () => reject("Failure to load image.");
          });
        }

        function handleBlobs() {
          console.log(blob);
          createImageFromBlob(imgdom, blob);
        }
        capture.addEventListener("click", handleBlobs, false);
      };

      socket.onerror = (error) => {
        console.log("Socket Error: ", error);
      };
      function captureHandler() {
        socket.send("someone is going to take a selfie");
      }
      function saveHandler() {
        socket.send("someone is going to save the selfie");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you already use imwrite... so what's the issue with serving that file?

Comment: yeah i can click "儲存" and save the image with IMWrite, so i can photogragh absolutely.
The problem is i want to not only take an image, but also show up the image in html.
My html page actually can get image data and show a "crash" image. This is what i want to solve.

Comment: that is entirely an issue with the server-side code that serves requests

Comment: Should i transform the img data to base64 before sending? But  there is no function can do such transformation in gocv

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by just encoding image to memory buffer then convert it to byte array before passing it. These actions compress the image size from 2764800 (=1920*1440)bytes to about fifty thousand bytes.

Replace

`w.Write(img.ToBytes())`

by

`buf, _ := gocv.IMEncode(".jpg", img)`
`w.Write(buf.GetBytes())`